# Jquery append and settimeout endless loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I'm try to display my json data in a table and refresh it periodically (to check if any new entries were added).  However, I ended up getting stuck in an endless loop.  The setTimeOut will keep appending old entries.  Can someone help me figure this out?

js fiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/eprte2m6/

js

```
<script>
  (function worker() {
  $.ajax({
    url: 'test.json',
    type: 'POST',
    data: 'json',
    success: function (response) {
        var trHTML = '';
        $.each(response, function (i, item) {
            trHTML += '<tr class="success"><td>' + item.type + '</td><td>' + item.date + '</td></tr>';
        });
        $('#monitor1').append(trHTML);
    },
  complete: function() {
    // Schedule the next request when the current one's complete
    setTimeout(worker, 5000);
  }
});
})();
</script>
```

test.json

```
[{
  "type":"Tablet", 
  "date":"02/03/14", 
},
{
  "type":"Tablet", 
  "date":"02/05/14", 
}]
```

html

```
<table class="table" id="monitor1">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>type</th>
          <th>Date</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
</table>
```

Comment: can you add a fiddle?

Comment: i added an js fiddle link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two options

**1)** You can clear the table before appending like bellow.

```
$('#monitor1 tbody').empty();
```

after append the data to table

```
$('#monitor1').append(trHTML);
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/eprte2m6/1/)

**2)** You can have a variable which will contain your previous `JSONdata` and at the time of response you can check, if both data are not same get the difference between both in another JSON. And update your table with that difference.

Comment: Thanks, option 1 worked for me!  Would it be possible to give me a demo of option 2?  I'm curious on how you would compare and print out the difference.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `.append`, instead use `.html` like below:

```
$('#monitor1').html(trHTML);
```

Comment: This somewhat works.  It lost my header labels on the table.  Thanks for replying.